# Сортировка чисел во вложенных массивах

Tags: javascript

Есть такой массив [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 5, 8 ], [ -4, -3 ], [ 7, 6 ], [ 5 ] ], они могут быть разные. Мне нужно Сравнить их ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ между собой и если разница будет только на 1 записать значение в счетчик. Нужно подсчитать количество парных массивом, где при сравнении между элементами расхождение не более 1. Думаю, что перед этим еще нужно отсортировать элементы по возрастанию. Подскажите какие манипуляции мне провести, чтобы воздействовать на вложенные массивы.

```
for (let i = 0; i<subArr.length; i++) { 
  arr.sort((a, b)=>a - b); 
}
```

Comment: "По сути мне их перед этим еще нужно отсортировать по возрастанию." - По какой сути, что отсортировать?

Comment: Проведите манипуляцию "цикл `for`".

Comment: a больше b на единицу. А также b больше a на единицу

Comment: Это и коню понятно, что нужен цикл for. Даже 2

Comment: Нет, одного цикла достаточно. Почену Вы не написали код с таким циклом?

Comment: for(let i = 0; i<subArr.length; i++){
        arr.sort((a, b)=>a - b);
      }

Comment: но он только главный массив сортирует

Comment: внутринние массивы не сортирует

Comment: [ [ -4, -3 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 5 ], [ 7, 6 ], [ 5, 8 ] ]

Comment: Что такое `subArr` и `arr`?

Comment: аргумент функции, значение которого массив переданный при консоль логе

Comment: Правильнее вот так. Но вижу, что внутренние массивы не сортирует for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr.sort((a, b)=>a[0] - b[1]);
      }

Comment: Что-то я не вижу в Вашем коде никакой "функции".

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем сортировать внешний или внутренниие массивы для того, чтобы посчитать количество внутренних массивов с разницей между числами в единицу.

Comment: function pairs(ar){
  //..
  let size = 2;
  const arr = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < ar.length; i+=2){
    let myArr = ar.slice(i, i+size);
    arr.push(myArr);
  }

      for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr.sort((a, b)=>a[0] - b[0]);
      }
  
  return arr;
 }
 console.log(pairs([1,2,5,8,-4,-3,7,6,5]));

Comment: Если есть краткий вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не очень понял, зачем сортировка. Но если нужно посчитать количество внутренних массивов с двумя числами, отличающимися на единицу, то можно так:

```js
const array = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 5, 8 ], [ -4, -3 ], [ 7, 6 ], [ 5 ] ];

let diffByOne = 0;

for (const inner of array) {
  if (inner.length === 2 && Math.abs(inner[0] - inner[1]) === 1) diffByOne++;
}

console.log(diffByOne);
```